# Is \10 allowed as a control-sequence name?

Tags: macros

At the beginning of Chapter 3: *Controlling TeX* of his TeXbook, Knuth explains that control sequences come in two flavours: *control words* and *control symbols*.

### Control words

> The first kind, like `\input`, is called a *control word*; it consists of an escape character followed by one or more *letters*, followed by a space or by something besides a letter. [...] In case you're wondering what a "letter" is, the answer is that TeX normally regards the 52 symbols A...Z and a...z as letters. The digits 0...9 are *not* considered to be letters, so they don't appear in control sequences of the first kind.

### Control symbols

> A control sequence of the other kind, like `\'`, is called a *control symbol*; it consists of the escape character followed by a single *nonletter*.

To test my understanding of those categories, I tried compiling the following code (with `pdftex`)... and was surprised not to get any error!

```
\def\10{foo}
\def\20{bar}
\10\20
\bye
```

In fact, a PDF output was generated without mishap:

[image]

The reason I'm puzzled is that `\10` and `\20` don't seem to fall into either category of allowed control-sequence names (as defined above):

1. They contain nonletters; therefore, they can't be considered *control words*.
2. They consist of the escape character (`\`) followed by *more* than just one nonletter; therefore, they can't be considered *control symbols*.

What am I missing?

Comment: @Roelof has the answer, but if you'd tried `\10` and `\11` it would have been obvious.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know; I chose the two names poorly. However, I understand how a newcomer to TeX can be fooled...

Comment: It should be added to the [most common mistakes...](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139873/what-are-the-most-common-mistakes-that-beginners-of-latex-and-friends-make).

Comment: @Marienplatz Do you really think this is common?

Comment: @marczellm: Yes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this case the `0` is part of the parameter text and acts as a delimiter token. So you are really defining `\1` and `\2` and are specifying that a `0` delimiter token is required after. You can use this mechanism for delimiting parameters.

Comment: Haaaaaa.... You're right! I'm so dumb -_-' Thanks!