# Use of New Math Operator doesn't match its definition

Tags: math-mode

I defined my self some macros for l- and L-spaces, to be specific some \l1, \L2, and so one. Now Latex throws errors while compiling, always exactly at the first \lx I defined:

> ! Use of \l doesn't match its definition.
>   l.31 \item[(v)] Für $f \in \l1
>   $ oder $f \in \L1$ heißt $f$ \emph{summierba...
>   If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
>   put`1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
>   made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
>   followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

It seems to ignore the numbers I put behind the \l or \L. I worked around it with using \lone, \Ltwo, and so on - so the matter is definitely not urgent. But I'm interested, why it behaves like that.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\l1}{\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})}
\DeclareMathOperator{\L1}{L^1(\mathbb{R})}
\DeclareMathOperator{\l2}{\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})}
\DeclareMathOperator{\L2}{L^2(\mathbb{R})}
\DeclareMathOperator{\linf}{\ell^\infty(\mathbb{Z})}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Linf}{L^\infty(\mathbb{R})}

\begin{document}

Für $f \in \l1$ oder $f \in \L1$ heißt $f$ \emph{summierbar} oder \emph{integrierbar}.
Für $f \in \l2$ oder $f \in \L2$ heißt $f$ \emph{Signal von endlicher Energie}.
Für $f \in \linf$ oder $f \in \Linf$ heißt $f$ \emph{beschränkt}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Control sequence names may contain only letters, except control sequence names consisting of only one character (called control symbols). This is a basic TeX rule. If there is already a letter in your control sequence name (`l`), what follows can be part of the name only if it's a letter. So, either you name your commands `\li`, `\lii`, etc. (using roman numbering), or you define a command that takes an argument: the figure (digit).

Comment: Thanks. Then this is solved.

Comment: This might be usedul: [Is \10 allowed as a control-sequence name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141888)

Comment: I'm defining the macro as `\newcommand{\ppp}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak p}\xspace}` and using it in a math environment as `\ppp_i`. It gives perfect results for the first few times (inside an `equation` environment, but suddenly shows this error when used inside `$$`. Is this a bug? I'm using overleaf.

Answer (score 3):

You can't define macros with numbers in their name.

However, for the particular case, you can get something similar, by exploiting the fact that a one-token argument needs not to be braced. Thus `\ls{1}` can be typed `\ls1` and the result will be the same. Beware that `\ls{3/2}` needs braces, of course.

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ls}[1]{\ell^{#1}(\mathbb{Z})}
\newcommand{\Ls}[1]{L^{#1}(\mathbb{R})}
\newcommand{\lsinf}{\ls{\infty}}
\newcommand{\Lsinf}{\Ls{\infty}}

\begin{document}

Für $f \in \ls1$ oder $f \in \Ls1$ heißt $f$ \emph{summierbar} oder \emph{integrierbar}.
Für $f \in \ls2$ oder $f \in \Ls2$ heißt $f$ \emph{Signal von endlicher Energie}.
Für $f \in \lsinf$ oder $f \in \Lsinf$ heißt $f$ \emph{beschränkt}.

\end{document}
```

Note that none of the symbols you want to define qualifies as an operator: they are just ordinary symbols.

Also, `\l` and `\L` are preempted and you should not redefine them: many Polish mathematicians were or are active in real analysis and you'd get into great troubles if trying to cite them in your documents.

[image]

Comment: This I like very much, thanks.

Comment: @frougon Thanks! I forgot to change the symbols after copy-paste.