# Feature (bug?) of dots notation in foreach-statement

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgffor

I want to draw something in `tikz` where the range of an inner loop depends on an outer loop (by construction of the math involved). I need to differentiate between even and odd number in the inner loop, and so my first approach was to define the range `\foreach \ell in {[begin],[begin+2],...,[end]}` and then deal with `\ell` and `\ell+1` separately in the loop (this code with square brackets cannot run, for the actual example see MWE below).

The problem is that - contrary to my expectation - for the the smallest range that occurs, `tikz` evaluates `\foreach \ell in {-1,1,...,-1}` as `\ell in {-1,1}`). The [documentation](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (p.910) says (square bracket and emphasis mine):

> In this situation, the part of the list reading `x,y,...,z` is
>   replaced by `x,x+d,x+2d,...,x+md`, where [`d=y-x` and] the last dots are
>   semantic dots, not syntactic dots. **The value `m` is the largest
>   number such that `x+md<=z`** if `d` is positive or such that `x+md>=z`
>   if `d` is negative.

My interpretation would be that `m` should be `0` in my case, but maybe that's hard to actually implement - or the behaviour could even be intentional.

In any case, I'd like to avoid having to split the loops and would like to find a way around it. I guess it would be possible to build an if-clause depending on the parity of `\ell` (to distinguish between even and odd, and just avoid specifying the second value of the list), this is just not that elegant either IMHO. But maybe there's no way around that as things stand...

As a brief sketch how I'd like my code to look like, here's an MWE (the desired result should just be one node at `(1,1)` with label "1"):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \j in {1} % scale (normally more!)
{
    % do something per scale here
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{2^(\j-1)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\istart{-\z}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\isecond{\istart+2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\iend{\z-2}
    \foreach \ell in {\istart,\isecond,...,\iend}
    {
        % do something for \ell here
        \node at (\ell,\ell) {\ell}; % just for illustration
        % do something for \ell+1 here
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `pgffor` always evaluates at least 2 values, the first one, and the second one. Only then it cares about the upper bound. It should have been stated in the manual. However, I'm sure that this has been asked before here :) I just can't find it now...

Comment: @tohecz: Is this intentional or would it just be too hard to discard the second value afterwards? I find the behaviour stated in the documentation to be very intuitive, and IMHO that's how it should work also for `m=0`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TikZ doesn't solve `x+md<z` equation to come up with the proper `m` or `d` for that matter. It starts adding `\isecond - \istart` amount in this case `2` after(!) evaluating the loop at `\istart` and `\isecond` because those points are given. Then checks whether `1+2 < -1` no then quits with *I'm done*.

You can use `\ifodd, \ifeven` if clauses if you want to branch off inside foreach. Or you can use `\pgfmathiseven{<number>}` and check the value of `\pgfmathresult`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \j in {1,...,4}
{
\ifodd\j\relax
\node at (0,\j) {odd};
\else
\node at (\j,0) {even};
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the `\ifodd`-trick, that at least is not as verbose as the `\pgfmathiseven{...}`-`\pgfmathresult` combination. I've therefore accepted the answer. Just out of curiosity, is there a TeX/PGF/performance-reason why the second value cannot be discarded in this case? I find the behaviour as stated in the documentation to be very intuitive and IMHO it should extend to `m=0`. (Ps. I made a similar comment to @tohecz after OP - sorry for the redundancy, I wanted to answer you both.)

Comment: @Axel Functionally, we can consider this usage as abuse of arrays because what you do is to first signal TikZ to expect an monotone array with `...` but then render the resulting array via using an endpoint that doesn't result with an array and moreover rendering `...` useless. The reason for not extending this to the cases you mentioned is because TeX floating point math is not precise. Hence given a `d`, computing `m` precisely is problematic in some cases. This implementation in that sense is a choice. I can see why you want to overload its definition but it would lead to extensive checks.

Comment: And from a coding perspective if you don't have an array you shouldn't utilize array tools for special case handling.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I can now at least understand the design decision better. On a different note, replacing `\ifodd` with `\ifeven` crashes for me - could it be that only the former is defined (together with the `\else`-clause this certainly covers all cases...)?

Comment: @Axel Ah, true. `\ifeven` doesn't have an `\else` clause (or that if switch doesn't work that way). Sorry my mistake.

Comment: No problem! The crash also happens without the `\else`-clause, though (on my machine)...

Comment: `\ifeven` does not exist [best practices - What are the most common mistakes that beginners of (La)TeX and Friends make? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139873/what-are-the-most-common-mistakes-that-beginners-of-latex-and-friends-make/141737#141737)...