# Document Title missing

Tags: titles

I am writing  paper for a Journal which should be 10 pt, double column format. It compiles as desired but the title doesnot appear anywhere when i compile it to pdf. Starting lines of the code are:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing}
\section{INTRODUCTION}
```

Please suggest what to do as I am new to Latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply forgot to put

```
\maketitle
```

after your title, which is the command that typesets the title.

The command `\title` by itself, only *defines* the title, but doesn't typeset it.

Adding that line, as in the following example

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing}
\maketitle
\section{INTRODUCTION}
\end{document}
```

shows your title.

[image]

Comment: This answer should be in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139873/what-are-the-most-common-mistakes-that-beginners-of-latex-and-friends-make.

Comment: @Fran You're right. I'll add it there.