# How can I use \ref to refer to a \label that's in another document?

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a math textbook, and hope to have a separate solutions manual.  I'd like for the manual to be able to refer to problems in the original book so that LaTeX, or I, can catch when the exercise numbers change since I am always revising them.  Also I may wish to skip some in the solutions manual.

It occurs to me that another solution would be to have one big, happy document but "turn off" the table of contents generation after the main text and then restart the page numbering for the manual.

Perhaps someone has a better solution than either of these.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/includeonly

Comment: The approach with the "happy document" sounds better than two documents. There are packages like `exercise` out there, which allow you to have the exercise and its solution next to each other in your source code, but can be configured to print the solutions at the end of the document.

Comment: Isn't `xr` exactly meant for this?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, excellent package that, who wrote it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Some strange British bloke, can't remember his name right now ;-)

Comment: you can try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314133/lecture-notes-with-embedded-exercises-and-separate-keys/314154#314154 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236512/need-to-produce-one-tex-document-in-multiple-volumes/236675#236675 IMHO it's not so good idea, separate document are separated.

Comment: Thanks for the "xr" and "exercise" tips.  I see xr in my LaTeX Companion now, but didn't see it right away in that vast resource.  I'm not sure quite how I'll do this but I'm sure I can make use of one or both of these on this or future projects.  Again thanks!  (The Companion says xr was developed by David Carlisle, "building on earlier work by Jean-Pierre Drucbert..."

Comment: Cool to have the xr bloke chime in!

Comment: You can give zref a try : https://www.ctan.org/pkg/zref

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments