# Is there a way I can manually reset or clear the citations in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Biblatex already provides options for `citereset` and `refsection` which make it easy to set up multiple (sub-)bibliographies for a document. However, the document I am creating uses manual partitions (above the level of "part") for my own purposes, as a form of "volume" in the wider work.

(The document is set up something like we see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236512/need-to-produce-one-tex-document-in-multiple-volumes).

I want citations to be consistent across parts, but when I reach one of these manual divides to a different "volume", I would like a separate citations section.

Is there a way I can manually reset the list of citations - and their numbers - at this point?

To add to the complication (potentially), I would like to be able to `\nocite{*}` to do a book-wide bibliography, through all volumes at the end.

I'm using `biblatex` with the `tufte-book` class, as well as the `subfiles` class for managing sub-files.

UPDATE:

So, according to the [documentation of biblatex](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) there is a `\citereset` command, however - compiling with `latexmk -pdf`, that is - I find that it doesn't seem to do this.

I.e., with the layout:

```
...the end. (The end of the last part in "Volume I")

% print bibliography for Volume I
\printbibliography
\citereset

% (code for manually ending this volume / starting next volume goes here)
\part{My Part}
\chapter{My Chapter}
% (no citations take place here)
```

...

```
...the end. (The end of the last part for "Volume II")

% print biliography for Volume II
\printbibliography
\citereset

% print bibliography for entire book
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
```

... what we find is that *every* bibliography has all the same references (the bib file I'm testing against in this case only has one reference).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I must confess I'm a bit confused here with your requirements. I believe `refsection` is the tool for what you are asking for, as far as I understand. To reset the numbering you should look to `printbibliography`'s option `resetnumbers` (which requires global option `defernumbers`). But then, if you reset the numbering for each part, how do you intend to obtain "consistent citations across parts" or especially a "book-wide bibliography"?

Comment: @gusbrs as the question outlines, I'm manually dividing the book into "volumes" which are _above_ the level of "part" logically - which means that there is no logical section I can use for the refsection option.

The book-wide bibliography would work via `\nocite{*}` _after_ the last volume has finished.

Comment: @SamWalls, you don't need the logical section to associate with the `refsection`. `refsection`s can be issued manually at any point in the document with the `refsection` environment or with `\newrefsection` (it must make sense, of course, and refsections can't be nested).

Comment: As to the global bibliography, if you reset the numbering per "volume", which number should the references get in the book-wide bibliography?

Comment: from your update, I also think you are misusing `\citereset`. This command resets the citation tracker (used for the likes as "idem, ibidem, op. cit." short forms and so on).

Comment: I think the ideal here would be for you to provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)/
[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407). A short compilable document which has the basic logical structure of what you are trying to achieve, your bibstyle/citestyle and some sample bibliographic entries.

Comment: @gusbrs you make a good point about the global bibliography - in fact, it may not be necessary given there is a bibliography for each volume, _and_ given the fact I'll likely be using an index.

As for a minimum example, I thought one might be required, but your answer has the right idea at any rate. I'll try it out, and whether or not it aids the problem, I'll make a MWE (eventually)...

Comment: SamWalls, from the point of view of referencing, the numeric citation style would indeed complicate things with numbers reset per volume to have a book-wide bibliography. But I must add that this could easily be accommodated with, e.g. an authoryear citation style.

Comment: @gusbrs Indeed, I used the `verbose` environment to get around this; which works well with the `tufte-book` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my view, the question isn't very clear as to specifics, which makes it difficult to answer. But here is a general structure you could use to do what I think you are trying to do.

Notice I'm using `\newrefsection` to divide at your "above part volume level" and provide structure for you to generate a book-wide bibliography based on a category "workscited".

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=numeric, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{workscited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{workscited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\defbibenvironment{bookwidebib}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%
% Here starts first volume
\newrefsection

\part{Part I}

\chapter{Chapter I.1}

\autocite{piccato}
\autocite{cotton}

\chapter{Chapter I.2}

\autocite{gerhardt}
\autocite{gonzalez}

\part{Part II}

\chapter{Chapter II.1}

\autocite{hammond}

\chapter{Chapter II.2}

\autocite{iliad}

\printbibliography

%%%%%%%
% Here starts second volume
\newrefsection

\part{Part III}

\chapter{Chapter III.1}

\autocite{knuth:ct}
\autocite{kullback}

\chapter{Chapter III.2}

\autocite{maron}
\autocite{massa}

\part{Part IV}

\chapter{Chapter IV.1}

\autocite{moore}

\chapter{Chapter IV.2}

\autocite{nussbaum}

\printbibliography

\clearpage
%%%%
% Book-wide bibliography
\newrefsection
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[env=bookwidebib, category=workscited, title={Book-wide bibliography}]

\end{document}
```