# Why my closing single quote is bold :(

Tags: quoting

```
The expression `\bf{\textbackslash [ formulae \textbackslash ]}`
```

the result is

> The expression ‘[ formulae ]’

(don't mind for not showing the '\' expressions in the result. That's not a problem ;) )

Always the second, or closing single quote being bold.

I don't know why this happens even though the quote is outside of the `\bf` command :(

Comment: Don't use `\bf`. Use `\textbf{}`.

Comment: If you really want to use `\bf`, use like this: `{\bfseries foo}`.

Comment: `\bf` is a few decades obsolete. In LaTeX, it shouldn't be used. It and `\bfseries` switch the font to bold indefinitely. They don't take an argument. `\textbf{bold text} and back to normal` or `{\bfseries bold text} and back to normal.

Comment: @Sigur I agree. There are no quotes in the input, are there?

Comment: @cfr, I think the input should start with `The expression...`. But who knows?!

Comment: In old syntax it would have been `{\bf ....}`, limiting the scope of the boldface, but as the other comments say, you should use `\textbf{...}` or perhaps `{\bfseries ...}`.

Comment: Please have a look at point 3 at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139907/100689

Answer (score -1):

if you use like this `\bf{\textbackslash [ formulae \textbackslash ]}` following words all are bold Use like below

`{\bf\textbackslash [ formulae \textbackslash ]}`

Comment: `\bf` is obsolete for over two decades.