# Why is the linespacing larger inside an empty environment?

Tags: environments, fontsize, line-spacing

I found myself perplex at the fact that the same command works a different line spacing when written inside an **empty** environment.

Could somebody explain why, or at least give me a method to make the line spacing inside the environment as tiny as it is outside?

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{footnotepar}{}{}%Empty environment

\begin{document}

\begin{footnotepar} %The line spacing here is too large
\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont This is a blind text. This is a blind text.
This is a blind text. This is a blind text.
This is a blind text. This is a blind text.
This is a blind text. This is a blind text. This is a blind text. 
\end{footnotepar}

\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont This is a blind text. This is a blind text.
This is a blind text. This is a blind text.
This is a blind text. This is a blind text.
This is a blind text. This is a blind text. This is a blind text. 
\end{document}
```

It outputs:

[image]

LaTeX Version: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.8.29)

Comment: The issue does not depend on the presence of an environment: try adding an empty line before `\end{footnotepar}`.  The problem is well known, I’ll try to find a question that already copes with it.

Comment: @GuM Thanks. Okay, know I understand why adding `\par` in the environment solves the problem. By the way adding `\par` in the definition is a bit more elegant than having to leave a space when using the environment—this is more error prone.

Comment: Yes, of course!  But my concern was only to put you on the right track: the simplest thing to think of is to add an empty line.

Comment: May I ask why you use an outdated TeX Live 2015 version? The current one is TeX Live 2019.

Comment: @Mensch It is the one provided by Xubuntu Xenial. :-\

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus Okay, but you get more and more issues with that outdated version. You should better install vanilla TeX LiVe, there is a question about installing it on this site ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyze what happens.

Your `footnotepar` environment does essentially nothing, except grouping the text inside it.

At `\end{footnotepar}`, TeX executes `\endgroup` and this undoes all settings done inside the environment, including `\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont`. This doesn't affect the size of the characters, because they have already entered TeX's scanner, but it *does* affect the interline spacing, for TeX only uses a single value for `\baselineskip` per paragraph and uses the value current at the time the paragraph is finished by `\par` (or an empty line, which is the same).

When does TeX see a `\par` in your example? At the empty line after `\end{footnotepar}` when `\endgroup` has already undone the instruction `\setlength{\baselineskip}{8pt}` performed by `\selectfont` inside the group. Too bad, the standard `\baselineskip` is used.

In the second paragraph, the `\par` is automatically supplied by `\end{document}`.

Everytime you do some font size change that involves division of text across lines, *ensure* a `\par` is issued at the appropriate time.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation! (I hope, it will be someone else useful)

Answer (score 0):

[image]I found a solution by tweaking here and there.

Just add `\par` to the definition of the environment

```
\newenvironment{footnotepar}{}{\par}%Empty environment
```

It works, but I am totally unsatisfied and I do not understand why it is so.

Comment: See, for example, [Why do I have to use \par if I change font size withing a group scope?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444039/69818).