# Break between lines because missing $

Tags: line-spacing

I made a document for my exam preparation

I get an error: missing $ inserted. And suddenly a huge space between the lines. Can you see where the error is comming from and why the line space is greate

```
% page setup
\documentclass[]{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{courier} % fonts
\usepackage{lmodern} % fonds
\usepackage{braket} % brakets

% enumeration
\usepackage{enumerate} % enumerations
\newcommand\sbullet[1][.5]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$\bullet$}}}}} % small bullet

% geometry
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\geometry{headsep=\baselineskip}

% headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyheadings}

% graphics
\usepackage{graphicx} % interface for optional arguments
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{xypic} %  variety of graphs and diagrams
\usepackage{float}

% Math / chemistry
\usepackage{amsmath} % mathematical features
\usepackage{amssymb} % math symbols
\usepackage{amsthm} % American Mathematical Society publications
\usepackage{siunitx} % SI units
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} % chemical symbols
\DeclareSIUnit\century{century}
\DeclareSIUnit\year{yr}
\DeclareSIUnit{\molar}{M}

% colums / paragraphs
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{parskip} % paragraph layouts

\usepackage{fancyvrb} % verbatim text 

\usepackage{hyperref} % cross-reference elements / generate PDF files

% table
\usepackage{enumitem} % for lists (in table)
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \Centering and \RaggedRight macros
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx} % for well-spaced horizontal lines
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} 
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newlength\colwidth

% fun
\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % symbols => used for \lighting
\usepackage{marvosym} % male / female sign 

% color
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table,x11names]{xcolor}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Seitenzahl mitte
\rfoot{Seite \thepage} % Seitenzahl rechts 
\rhead{Cheat sheet klinische Chemie} % Kopfzeile rechts oben
\lhead{$\mathrightbat$} % Kopfzeile links oben 
\fancyheadoffset{0.01 cm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\newgeometry{top=0.55in,bottom=0.55in,right=0.3in,left=0.3in} 
\begin{paracol}{4}
\begin{small}
 \tiny
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
h\\
a  : \\
b :  
\end{small}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

it should be like this:
[image: how it should look like]

and not like this:
[image: to large space]

Comment: Not related to the problem at hand, but you [should not use `\\\` to end a paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines)

Comment: You are setting tiny text on a normal baseline, leave a blank line before `\end{small}` so that the `\tiny` baseline is used

Comment: Amazing! Thank you :D

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444039/why-do-i-have-to-use-par-if-i-change-font-size-withing-a-group-scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbols from `halloweenmath` are *math-mode* symbols. The error comes from

```
\lhead{\mathrightbat}
```

which should be

```
\lhead{$\mathrightbat$}
```

instead.

Comment: I did this but the space between the lines is still large