Why does linespacing changes?
I want to create a document, where the spacing between the lines is 1.5. But for some reason the linespacing changes after a \vfill. I read that this can happen, but how can I force the linespacing to be 1.5 or prevent this from happening?
As I am a LaTeX beginner I am sorry if this is a often asked question. I am also thankful for general suggestions on good practices of writing LaTeX :)
This is the code for the page:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\linespread{1.5} % Zeilenabstand auf 1,5 setzen
\usepackage[top=3 cm, bottom=2 cm, left=2 cm, right=3.5cm]{geometry} % Ränder der Seite definieren
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutsche Formate und Sprache
\usepackage{graphicx} % Zum einbinden von Grafiken
%\usepackage{url} % Einfach einbinden von URLs

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
%%%%%%%%%% Sperrvermerk %%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%% Auskommentieren wenn benötiggt %%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\begin{large}
Art der Arbeit Nr.
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
Vorname Name
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
\textbf{\LARGE Sperrvermerk}
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
Folgende/s Kapitel unterliegt/unterliegen aufgrund der Verwendung vertraulicher Daten einem Sperrvermerk und sind/ist ausschließlich für die zuständige Fachleiterin / den zuständigen Fachleiter und die betreuende Prüferin / den betreuenden Prüfer einsichtig zu machen:
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
\begin{tabular}{l l}
0 & Name des Kapitels\\
0.0 & Name des Unterkapitels\\
\end{tabular}
\linebreak
\vfill
Eine Kurzfassung der Arbeit, die ausschließlich die nicht gesperrten Kapitel bzw. Unterkapitel enthält, wird unter der Bezeichnung (Dateiname) auf beigefügtem Datenträger zusätzlich zur Verfügung gestellt.
\end{large}
\end{center}
\newpage

And this is the outcome:


see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444039/36296

you need a blank line befire \end{large}

unrelated to baseline space but avoid using \linebreak and never use adjacent \linebreak as you have here.

There is no large environment; the fact that you don't get warnings or errors is an implementation artifact. The obvious problem using it is that the end of paragraph is after \end{large}, which kills the effect of \large initiated by \begin{large}: the text is already typeset in large size, but the paragraphing is done by \par, too late.
For the vertical space, \linebreak isn't the right tool.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=3 cm, bottom=2 cm, left=2 cm, right=3.5cm]{geometry} % Ränder der Seite definieren
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutsche Formate und Sprache
\usepackage{graphicx} % Zum einbinden von Grafiken
%\usepackage{url} % Einfach einbinden von URLs

\linespread{1.5} % Zeilenabstand auf 1,5 setzen

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

%%%%%%%%%% Sperrvermerk %%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%% Auskommentieren wenn benötiggt %%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}\large

Art der Arbeit Nr.

\vspace{\stretch{1}}

Vorname Name

\vspace{\stretch{1}}

\textbf{\LARGE Sperrvermerk}

\vspace{\stretch{1}}

Folgende/s Kapitel unterliegt/unterliegen aufgrund der Verwendung 
vertraulicher Daten einem Sperrvermerk und sind/ist ausschließlich 
für die zuständige Fachleiterin / den zuständigen Fachleiter und 
die betreuende Prüferin / den betreuenden Prüfer einsichtig zu machen:

\vspace{\stretch{1}}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
0 & Name des Kapitels\\
0.0 & Name des Unterkapitels\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{\stretch{2}}

Eine Kurzfassung der Arbeit, die ausschließlich die nicht gesperrten 
Kapitel bzw. Unterkapitel enthält, wird unter der Bezeichnung (Dateiname) 
auf beigefügtem Datenträger zusätzlich zur Verfügung gestellt.
\end{center}

\end{document}


