# Reducing the width of children in a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I wish to reduce the width between the children in a tree.
Look at the image given below:
[image]

The right child of F is getting hidden due to left child negation(r).This is how my latex file looks like as of now

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
                            every node/.style = {
                                shape=rectangle,
                                rounded corners,
                                draw,
                                align=center,
                                top color=white,
                                bottom color=blue!5}]]
                    \node {$\varnothing$}
                        child{node {F}
                            child{node {$\lnot$p}
                                    child{node {$\lnot$p$\lor$ q}}
                                    child{node {$\lnot$q}}
                                }
                            child{node {p}}
                            }
                        child{node {$\lnot$r}
                                child{node {$\lnot$r$\lor$ s}}
                                child{node {$\lnot$s}}
                            }
                        child{node {r}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
     
    
\end{document}
```

How do I fix this issue?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: Hey, I have added fully compilable code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer to your tree problem is don't use the base TikZ tree methods. Their syntax is clunky and it does no automatic positioning of nodes (as you have discovered.) Instead use `forest` for making trees. It has a much simpler syntax and does automatic packing of nodes to make trees as compact as possible, but allows you to make them less compact as needed.

But there are many other mistakes in the code you've shown us. It seems like you need to read a good basic introduction of how to use LaTeX more generally. Here are some things I've noticed and fixed (there may be others I've missed.)  For a list of common mistakes beginners make see [What are the most common mistakes that beginners of (La)TeX and Friends make?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139873/2693). See also [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/2693) and especially the new  https://www.learnlatex.org/ site.

1. Numbering things manually. One of the nicest things about LaTeX is its ability to number elements for you. You should never have to number anything manually. So I've replaced your manually numbered paragraphs with `\subsection` commands.
2. If something looks like an itemized list, then make it an itemized list: I've replaced your manual "What will we learn" section with an `itemize` environment using the `enumitem` package to format the items.
3. Displayed math is centred by using `\[ ... \]` not `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`.  And in LaTeX you should *never* use `$$ ... $$` to introduce displayed math.  See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/2693) and also [What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/2693) for more options.
4. You should never use `\\` to end a paragraph, and in running text you should generally not use it at all.  See [When to use \par and when \\, \newline, or blank lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664/2693).

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[small]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{mynode/.style={ shape=rectangle,
                                rounded corners,
                                draw,
                                align=center,
                                top color=white,
                                bottom color=blue!5,
                                math content}}


\author{\emph{Muppuri Siva Jagadesh}}
\title{\textbf{Discrete Maths}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhf{}
\rhead{
    Assignment 1
}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{LECTURE 1: SAT PROBLEM}
    
    \subsection{What will we learn?}
    \begin{itemize}[label=$\rightarrow$]
        \item Satifiability
       \item Conjunctive Normal Forms
     \end{itemize}   
    \subsection{Satisfiability}
        A compound proposition is satisfiable if it is true for at least one truth assignment of the underlying propositional variables.
        \[
            \text{e.g.: } (p \lor \lnot q) \land (q \lor \lnot r)
      \]
        
    \subsection{}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Replace all $\Leftrightarrow$ symbol (if any)
            \[
                (p \Leftrightarrow q) \equiv (p \rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow p)
            \]
            \item \[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} = 1\]
        \end{enumerate}
        
    
    \subsection{}
        \begin{forest}for tree={mynode, s sep=1cm}
        [\varnothing
            [F
                [\lnot p 
                    [\lnot p \lor q ]
                    [\lnot q ]
                ]
                [p ]
            ]
            [\lnot r 
                [\lnot r \lor s ]
                [\lnot s ]
            ]
            [r]
        ]
    \end{forest}                        
      
    
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thats true .I have just started learning Latex for my course at college. It is just my second day using it. This is a test file in which I wanted to test out all math symbols that I am gonna use in my course! Hence , the content makes no sense as it is a Test file.Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 2):

You should only place here the code necessary for your question, personal information and code that does not relate to your problem should not be placed in the question.

Here, it is enough to adjust the distance between the children with the `level 1` and `level 2` style.

```
level 1/.style={sibling distance=10em},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=5em},
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}


\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[%sibling distance=10em,
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=10em},
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=5em},
                            every node/.style = {
                                shape=rectangle,
                                rounded corners,
                                draw,
                                align=center,
                                top color=white,
                                bottom color=blue!5}]]
                    \node {$\varnothing$}
                        child{node {F}
                            child{node {$\lnot$p}
                                    child{node {$\lnot$p$\lor$ q}}
                                    child{node {$\lnot$q}}
                                }
                            child{node {p}}
                            }
                        child{node {$\lnot$r}
                                child{node {$\lnot$r$\lor$ s}}
                                child{node {$\lnot$s}}
                            }
                        child{node {r}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks ,that worked